# Need to write regular expression in Javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

Need to write regular expression in javascript on a field with constraint -

The name can be up to 80 characters long. It must begin with a word character, and it must end with a word character or with ''. The name may contain word characters or '.', '-', ''."

Example -

Allowed strings -

```
abc.'
abc-'.'
ab-.''-a
```

Not allowed strings -

```
rish a
rish.-
```

What I have tried so far:

```
!/^[A-Za-z.-'']{1,80}$/.test(Name)
```

Comment: What have you tried ?

Comment: @jo_va !/^[A-Za-z.-'']{1,80}$/.test(Name)

Comment: Is there a minimum length?

Comment: Hi! Please take the [tour] (you get a badge!) and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) Your best bet here is to do your research, [search](/help/searching) for related topics on SO, and give it a go. ***If*** you get stuck and can't get unstuck after doing more research and searching, post a [mcve] of your attempt and say specifically where you're stuck. People will be glad to help.

Comment: `What I have tried so far:` and how is that not doing what you want?

Comment: @Sweeper yes one character

Comment: @JaromandaX it allows strings not ending with words or ' '.

Comment: Don't you get an error "Range out of order in character class"? 
Because you need to escape - character, like this: [A-Za-z.\-'']

Comment: @Risha you need to start writing in why this doesn't do what you want, into the question. Comments don't last forever around here.

Answer (score 2):

I guess, you're looking for something like this:

`^(?=[A-Za-z])[A-Za-z\.\-']{0,79}[A-Za-z']$`

To explain:

`^(?=[A-Za-z])`: Check, that the string starts with a word character. This is a look-ahead assertion, so it will NOT take a part in the match. The rest of the pattern must still account for at least 1 and max 80 characters.

`[A-Za-z\.\-']{0,79}`: First and middle characters, therefore max 79 chars. Minimum of one is enforced with the last character.

`[A-Za-z']$`: Ends with a letter or apostrophe.

Testable here: https://regex101.com/r/AOQojT/1

Comment: thank you. It is helpful. Specially the explanation of look-ahead assertion part.

Comment: Assertions are a little known, even littler understood, but massively powerful feature. I recommend anyone working with regexes to inform themselves about and understand them, because they are very useful.

Answer (score 0):

Using look-ahead assertion is a very clever way of solving this.
Another way would be using OR operator:

```
^[a-zA-Z]$|^[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z.\-']{0,78}[a-zA-Z']$
```

It simply checks whether:

`^[a-zA-Z]$` - there is only one word character

**Or** |

`^[a-zA-Z]$` - one word character at the very beginning of given string
`[a-zA-Z.\-']{0,78}` - from zero to seventy-eight characters. . (dot) does not have to be escaped, since it has no special meaning in character set. 
`[a-zA-Z']` - one word character or apostrophe

Thus it validates strings longer, than 1 character.

https://regex101.com/r/CB1uOw/1